# Using CARTO in a different language (multilanguage)?

Tags: carto, carto-js, internationalization

Is it possible to configure CARTO, CARTO Builder, etc to be available in different languages e.g. Spanish, French, Portuguese?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to set CARTO Builder and dashboard to a different language than English (disclaimer: I work at CARTO).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It's not possible as its not developed a tool that allows it, but is it possible to do it?

Comment: I suppose so. CARTO platform is OS, so if you know what you are doing, you could install and customize it. But this approach is going to be hard to develop and maintain.